# In VSCode how to set the working directory of a new python interactive window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When executing `Jupyter: Create Interactive Window` in VScode a new interactive window is opened, how to control the working directory this fresh python interpreter?

Steps in Mac OS:

1. cmd+shift+P
2. type `Jupyter: Create Interactive Window`
3. a new interactive window is opened
4. in there type `!pwd` to see the working directory

How to control in which directory this is? I am working with a multi-root workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the order of the paths listed in the work space file (e.g. `my_workspace.code-workspace`) controls the default working directory when launching a new interactive window.

The workspace file looks like

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "."
    },
    {
      "path": "../my_path_1"
    },    {
      "path": "../my_path_2"
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "git.enabled": false
  }
}
```

The new interactive window will have the working directory of the first path listed above. In this case the the path where `my_workspace.code-workspace` is located.

Comment: so far this is my answer, that is how I can control the the working directory of the newly launched interactive window

Answer (score 0):

I frequently change directories to run multiple scripts in the same workplace, and end up clicking the directory in the file explorer and `Copy Path`, then just execute the `cd` magic command in the interactive prompt:

```
cd C:/Users/..../dir/path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see where vscode starts with this code :

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

sometimes vscode interactive starts in /src and sometimes the root workspace. If you want the interpreter to start one folder up e.g. in /src in /.vscode directory in the file settings.json add  the following files.

"terminal.integrated.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
"jupyter.notebookFileRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src"

This might give issues in some projects that already start in /src. It works for the interactive window for me.